# Force every destination IP address on certain ports to go through a specific gateway IP only on windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I have one network adapter interface connected to 2 gateways. I am trying to dedicate traffic on certain ports (80, 443, 8080, 8443) to go only through gateway IP #1 and everything else by default should go through gateway IP #2.

In windows settings I can define the default gateway, so what else left is how do I route everything on the previously mentioned ports through gateway IP #1

Comment: I may add a second network adapter and config each interface to use a certain gateway, but that if only what I want is not possible on windows

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows does not support this, regardless of the number of interfaces. You'll need an additional gateway – most likely Linux-based or RouterOS-based – that would use PBR (policy-based routing) to select the appropriate routing table based on packet ports. The Windows system would only use that one gateway, while the additional gateway would be the one to have both routes.

Comment: Unfortunately my routers doesn't support routing rules by ports. It does only by source and destination IP which is not useful in my case

Comment: Yeah, so you will need to get an additional router that does. Any generic Linux machine will do, or possibly a router with OpenWRT in it (though I don't know how to do it via OpenWRT's specific config system, but it's still Linux), or even a RouterOS device. (Though to be honest, your router's ability to route by source IP is already quite rare, and most likely implemented via the same PBR.)

Answer (score 0):

Windows by itself doesn't support routing by rules. You need third-party
software for that.

You could setup a proxy server on your computer and design it as the
default gateway. You will need to program the proxy server to route
the requests according to the port numbers.

I believe that [Squid for Windows](https://squid.diladele.com/)
is one possible solution, although there will be a learning curve.

The article
[Transparently filtering HTTPS with Squid and Policy Based Routing](https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/policy_based_routing_squid/index.html)
might give you a starting point.

(<sub>Disclaimer : I have never used Squid and cannot help any further than
point you on the way.</sub>)